# Поиск двух минимальных элементов в массиве

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Помогите =( Находится второе число, но совершенно другое, пробовал через отладчик найти, не могу понять в чем проблема.

```
        int[] a = new int[] { 5, 12, 13, 2, 1, 9, 15, 19, 6 };
        int oneMinValue = a[0];
        int twoMinValue = a[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if (oneMinValue > a[i])
            {
                oneMinValue = a[i];
            }
         else if (twoMinValue > a[i] & twoMinValue <= oneMinValue)
            {
                twoMinValue = a[i];
            }


        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(oneMinValue);
            Console.WriteLine(twoMinValue);
        }
```

Comment: А зачем вы вообще выводите в цикле?...

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо не забывать, что инвариант — `oneMinValue` не превышает `twoMinValue`.

Так что вот как должно быть...

```
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if (twoMinValue > a[i])
            {
                twoMinValue = a[i];
            }
            if (twoMinValue < oneMinValue)
            {
                int tmp = twoMinValue;
                twoMinValue = oneMinValue;
                oneMinValue = tmp;
            }

        }
```

Ну и выводить в цикле совсем ни к чему:

```
        Console.WriteLine(oneMinValue);
        Console.WriteLine(twoMinValue);
```

Вот, смотрите [результат](https://ideone.com/Fjn4TF).

**Update**

По замечанию DmitryK:

```
        int oneMinValue = a[0];
        int twoMinValue = a[1];

        if (twoMinValue < oneMinValue)
        {
            int tmp = twoMinValue;
            twoMinValue = oneMinValue;
            oneMinValue = tmp;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if (twoMinValue > a[i])
            {
                twoMinValue = a[i];
            }
            if (twoMinValue < oneMinValue)
            {
                int tmp = twoMinValue;
                twoMinValue = oneMinValue;
                oneMinValue = tmp;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Пропущено одно граничное условие - если минимальный элемент будет `a[0]`, то ответ будет неправильным - оба значения выведутся одинаковыми.

Comment: @DmitryK Логично. Постарался исправиться :)

Answer (score 0):

У вас условие никогда не выполняется.

```
if (twoMinValue > a[i] & twoMinValue <= oneMinValue)
```

Поскольку `oneMinValue` при проходе по массиву всегда является минимальным из уже встреченных чисел, то условие `twoMinValue <= oneMinValue` всегда ложное.
Должно быть что-то вроде такого:

```
int oneMinValue = a[0];
int twoMinValue = a[1];

if(oneMinValue > twoMinValue)
   swap(oneMinValue, twoMinValue);

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
   if (oneMinValue > a[i])
   {  
      twoMinValue = oneMinValue;
      oneMinValue = a[i];
   }
   else
   if(twoMinValue > a[i])
      twoMinValue = a[i];
```